# ¿Cómo puedo renombrar un repositorio?

Tags: git

Tengo un repositorio en GitLab con un nombre **repo**. Estoy trabajando con él en local tras hacer un:

```
git clone git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo.git
```

Ahora decidí cambiarle el nombre a **repo_nuevo** y así lo hice desde la interfaz de GitLab. Esto quiere decir que a partir de ahora para inicializarlo debo hacer:

```
git clone git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo_nuevo.git
                                       ^^^^^^
```

Sin embargo, ya tengo el repositorio descargado en un directorio y estoy trabajando desde allí, por lo que no necesito hacer `git clone` sino simplemente cambiar la referencia.

Lo que hice de momento es:

```
mv repo repo_nuevo
```

Pero sé que esto es algo opcional.

¿Cuál es el proceso para cambiar la referencia y que cuando haga un `git pull` (o lo que sea) git ya *vea* la nueva dirección?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Al cambiar el nombre del repositorio desde el servidor, en la raíz del repositorio clonado hay que realizar el siguiente proceso:

**Opción resumida**

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo_nuevo.git
```

**Paso a paso**

1. Comprobar el estado de los servidores de Git:

   ```
   git remote -v

   origin  git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo.git (fetch)
   origin  git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo.git (push)
   ```
2. Quitar el servidor `origin`:

   ```
   git remote remove origin
   ```
3. Agregar la nueva dirección del repositorio:

   ```
   git remote add origin git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo_nuevo.git
   ```
4. Comprobar que el nuevo repositorio se encuentre asociado:

   ```
   git remote -v

   origin  git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo_nuevo.git (fetch)
   origin  git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo_nuevo.git (push)
   ```
5. Realizar `pull` y `push` a `origin`:

   ```
   git pull origin master
   git push origin master
   ```
6. Solucionar los *merge* que se puedan presentar.

Si el proceso se realiza como aquí se muestra no debería haber mayor problema.

[Documentación de GIT REMOTE](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

Comment: ¡Fantástico! Yo hice `git remote set-url git clone git@gitlab.blabla.com:yo/repo_nuevo.git` y también funcionó.

Comment: El código @fedorqui al parecer lo escribió mal, pues este no funciona, lo correcto es `git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:yo/repo_nuevo.git` con este código es posible cambiar la referencia del repositorio a un determinado servidor.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, al copiar y pegar me hice un lío. Efectivamente, lo que me funcionó fue `git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:yo/repo_nuevo.git`. Son equivalentes, ¿verdad?

Comment: Si, el proceso básicamente es el mismo, una es la manera corta de realizar ese proceso y a mi parecer es la correcta y la otra es como el paso a paso, así lo he dejado expuesto en la respuesta, gracias por la aclaración, es de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Gracias a ti por tu dedicación y buena respuesta. Por cierto, ¡bienvenido al sitio!